# I would like a few pointers for a program I'm trying to create in Python 3.3.3

Tags: python, random, dice

So far, I've had a few bumps in the road, but I've been able to correct them, though my programming is quite sloppy as I've just started Python.  The idea is to create a dice game called "Pig."  The idea is that a user can roll or hold each turn and each subsequent roll adds to the players pot, though if you roll a 1 it's a bust and your pot is reset.  Here is my program so far:

```
import random
die = random.randint(1,6)

R = (die)
r = (die)
H = (0)
h = (0)

User_Score = 0
Computer_Score = 0

pot1 = 0
pot2 = 0
User = input('Hello! Enter your name:')
Computer = 'AI'

if roll_again is 1:
    return take_turn(User)
elif roll_again is 0:
    take_turn(Computer)

print (User,"'s pot: ",pot1)
print (Computer,"'s pot: ",pot2)

if pot1 >= 50:
    User_Score += 1
if pot2 >= 50:
    Computer_Score += 1

def roll_die(random):
    numbers = [0]*6
    for n in range (1,6):
        die = random.randint (1,6)
        numbers = n
    return numbers

def take_turn(User):
    print ("It is your turn",User, input("Hit Enter to continue.")
    if input == True
(roll_die(random))
    if die == int(1)
        (pot1) is 0 and print("Die: 1 Pot: Bust! 0")
        else:
            print ("Die:",die, "Pot:",pot1)
        (pot1) =+ die
        (R,r,H,h) is raw_input ("(R)oll again or (H)old?")
        if input is(R,r)
            (roll_again) is 1
        else input is (H,h)
            (roll_again) is 0
        print (User,"'s pot: ",pot1)
        print (Computer,"'s pot: ",pot2)
    else
        return take_turn(User)
take_turn(User)
take_turn(Computer)
```

I seem to have a syntax error around the line 40 (I'm not sure exactly which line).  Which is "if die == int(1)".  I'm sure there are plenty of errors after that which I can solve on my own time, but getting past this roadblock would really be helpful! Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if die == int(1)` => `if die == int(1):`

Comment: But why are you doing `int(1)`?  Just `1` is plenty.

Comment: Further, it seems you put parenthesis around lots of things that don't need them.  For example, `h = (0)` can (read: should) be `h = 0`.  This isn't Lisp :)

Comment: In general, you are missing many `:`, missing many closing parenthesis, have indentation errors, and are misusing `is` (you want `==` in every case you use `is`).

Comment: Thank you for all of your tips.  I'm fixing all I can right now but I'm using two different computers to program this game, and it seems one doesn't like colons as well as throws out the idea of "==". Strange.

Comment: I don't think that's possible :/ Sounds like a symptom of not copying the files correctly or somesuch.

Answer (score 0):

There is no closing parenthesis at the end of line 38.

> print ("It is your turn",User, input("Hit Enter to continue.")

This might be the error

Comment: There are about 10 syntax errors, it's tough to say this is "the" error, although it *definitely* is one (and representative of other errors).

Comment: Yeah I know there are a ton of errors! I just started programming, so trying to handle all of this on top of calc 2 and discreet math has me a little flustered.